# Is the Serial Port pin CTS an inverse logic, meaning if you have a logic high input the PC terminal will register a logic low?

Tags: serial, port

Because as I see my code accessing the serial port I see a boolean 'false' value of the CTS instead of 'true' where as my input is high. Please kindly confirm and give a little explanation. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Your question is a good question BUT it is answered very well on very many web pages and has been for many years. It may been that your circumstances prevent you accessing such resources - and if so then asking here as you did is fine. However, if you are able to access web resources I suggest you try that first and then you will be able to ask an even better question if you still do not understnd what you find.

Answer (score 1):

Check the [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232) page out, particularly this bit:

Control signals are logically inverted with respect to what one sees on the data transmission lines. When one of these signals is active, the voltage on the line will be between +3 to +15 volts. The inactive state for these signals is the opposite voltage condition, between −3 and −15 volts. Examples of control lines include request to send (RTS), clear to send (CTS), data terminal ready (DTR), and data set ready (DSR).

Answer (score 1):

RS232 signals are all negative logic.

- Logic 1 = logic high = voltage low or negative
- Logic 0 = logical low = voltage high or positive

Comment: @Kortuk - Apparently even mild comment on the lack of the most basic web searching or basic research is absolutely discouraged here. If no guidance is given or allowed when the most basic of standards are not met we can expect a continuation of the very poor standard of question formulation, lack of basic research and prior thought that we see here in a significant **minority** of cases.

Comment: you can leave a comment to the poster on the quality of the question and you can downvote if you find it a poor question. The answer space is space for an answer, sorry if I made you feel your feedback was not correct. In the answer teaching someone how to go about looking it up would be more then useful. Please forgive me if I corrected something that was flagged as offensive.

Comment: @Kortuk - if that sort of advice is/was felt to be offensive then it's going to be a long slow play-way learning curve to achieving any sort of mastery of either the subject or of the information rich environment we all swim in. If it's offensive to tell people that the answer has been available for many years from many sources (both of which are true) and that doing a basic search first would be a good idea, then sorry indeed are those who wish to learn by any alternate methods.

Comment: it is a RTFM answer, if you have seen that. Again, you can post it as a comment, you can also downvote. But did it answer the question in any way? Did it make your answer say, "you are incompetent/lazy, but here is the simple answer you should have found yourself." Leave a comment on the question for feedback, leave an answer as an answer since it is what people find when they google. On the note of offensive, that is just the way it used to show up in queues. It is now, "this is not welcome in our community"

Comment: Difficult one this - I didn't see the removed text as "offensive", but maybe it's simply safer to *never* point out these things given the infinite number of (usually unexplained initially) reasons that a person may have for missing an "obvious" solution, and the varying views on what is deemed offensive. Would seem a shame to "censor" such information too much though, as learning how to ask questions and learning how to research effectively is (I think) part of the toolset. It didn't answer the *worded" question, but it probably passed on some valuable experience.

Comment: @Kortuk - I know I'm 'flogging a dead horse' here, but, if "our community" encourages utter removal of all forms of guidance towards self betterment in even the most trivial or blatant cases then it may go a long way towards explaining the amazing amount of very poor initial questions here. They get better after a few cycles of pointing out what is obviously missing, but nobody seems to care. "How can I?" would just about pass muster as a starting question at present.

Comment: @Oli and Russell, I am sorry if I am not clear. This can be posted as a comment to the question. It is not censored, it is just not part of the answer field. Users might also not upvote based on technical content, but instead that you are pointing out it should have been easy to find. Again, offensive is the wrong word, it is what the site used to use in flag text that moderators received. It is better to say it did not add to the answer and was not part of an answer. Just post it as a comment if you would like to leave the feedback.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, I care about he community and feedback positive and negative are important, I sometimes would prefer long discussions were taken to chat instead of cluttering the site, but other than that feel free to discuss and question away.